# WPF Designer View irritation - no textwrap

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008, word-wrap

I'm not sure if there is a solution to this. But it is niggling at me and irritating me.

I'm using WPF and Visual Studio 2008. I've designed a beautiful UI :). I have a help text control which is contextual as to which control has been clicked. When the app first loads it has default text set. "Welcome to the X screen here you can ..........". This is inside a user control, which sits inside a tab control, inside a window. The user control has minheight and minwidth set (I suspect this is why the designer does what it does).

I set the initial text in the XAML, with textwrapping set to true. The problem is that the designer decides to put this all on one line - which really throws out the view (I can't see the entire UI in one screen at 100%, if I scale it down I can't read things, etc)

Is there anyway to get around this (other than setting the text in the code instead - (is there any difference between doing this and doing it in the xaml?!))
Maybe that is the only solution.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<TabControl>
  <TabItem MaxWidth="200">
    <TabItem.Header>
      <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
        hi asdfkjl; asdf asdf asdf sdaf sadf  safd sf   sadf  fasf asd f asdf as df sadf asd f asdf sd f sadf as df asdf asd f asdf as df
      </TextBlock>
    </TabItem.Header>
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

I tested it in kaxaml and it wraps like you'd expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a `FlowDocumentReader` control for this? I haven't experienced the problem you described but this control was very useful for me to render help text.